# SMTP mail is not sent in php

Tags: php, email, smtp

```
<?php
include('phpmailer.php');
class Mail extends PhpMailer
{
    // Set default variables for all new objects
    public $From     = 'my_email_id@gmail.com';
    public $FromName = SITETITLE;
    public $Host     = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    public $Mailer   = 'smtp';
    public $SMTPAuth = true;
    public $Username = 'my_enail_id@gmail.com';
    public $Password = 'mypass';
    public $SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    public $WordWrap = 75;

public function subject($subject)
{
    $this->Subject = $subject;
}

public function body($body)
{
    $this->Body = $body;
}

public function send()
{
    $this->AltBody = strip_tags(stripslashes($this->Body))."\n\n";
    $this->AltBody = str_replace("&nbsp;", "\n\n", $this->AltBody);
    return parent::send();
}
```

}

This is my code. `phpmailer.php` is this [code](https://github.com/daveismyname/loginregister/blob/master/classes/phpmailer/phpmailer.php)

I am a newbie to php.

this is how I am invoking `send()` method.

```
        $mail = new Mail();
        $mail->setFrom(SITEEMAIL);
        $mail->addAddress($to);
        $mail->subject($subject);
        $mail->body($body);

        if(!$mail->send())
        {
           echo 'There was an error sending the message';
           exit;
        }
```

Comment: What errors do you get? > `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: so what errors do you get? set debug `$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;` and also have you enabled less secure apps in gmail account?

Answer (score 0):

You can t send email from localhost without installing [sendmail plugin and configure it](https://www.glob.com.au/sendmail/) if you use wamp on Windows 
If you you use an other PHP server  or operating system specify it

Comment: I am running it on https://c9.io/

Comment: Sending email directly from our servers using the SMTP port is blocked, otherwise spammers would use it to send out spam. Here are a couple things to note: If you're like to send email from within Cloud9, you can use Google Compute Engine partner services, like SendGrid, Mandrill, or Google Apps …
Take a look  here : https://community.c9.io/t/how-can-i-send-email-from-my-app/1262